# Change the position of slider according the value of input

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

How can change the position of slider according to what value put in input? Im run out of ideas. Any help would be appreciated.

this is my `html`

```
<h1>HTML Slider Test</h1>

<div id="slider"></div>

<p>Your slider has a value of <span id="slider-value">
<input type="text">
</span></p>
```

this is the `script`

```
$("#slider").slider(
    {
      value:100,
      min: 0,
      max: 500,
      step: 50,
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#slider-value" ).val( ui.value );
      }
    }
);

$( "#slider-value input" ).val(  $('#slider').slider('value') );
```

this is the fiddle

[Sample](https://jsfiddle.net/5cqe8nLs/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the [Docs for jQueryUI](https://api.jqueryui.com/slider/).
You need to use `$( ".selector" ).slider( "value", 55 );`

### [Here's a demo](https://jsfiddle.net/5cqe8nLs/1/)

```
$('input').on('change keyup', function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
  $( "#slider" ).slider( "value", val );
});
```

You can also use just `change` if the `keyup` is too aggressive.